# Google Api keys / credentials will not work

Tags: python, google-api

Im attempting to use google bards API and or google gemini and no matter how I place the Api keys I get the same error "google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application"

here is the code its pretty simple

`

```
import google.generativeai as palm  # Assuming you have this library installed
import os


# Set the API key
palm.configure(api_key=os.environ.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY')  )
defaults = {
    'model': 'models/text-bison-001',
   'temperature': 0.5,
   'candidate_count': 1,
    'max_output_tokens': 1024,
    'stop_sequences': [],
}

     def getBardResponse(prompt, settings=defaults):
    response = palm.generate_text(**settings, prompt=prompt)
    return response.result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_prompt = input("Enter a prompt: ")  # Get user input dynamically
    bard_response = getBardResponse(user_prompt)
    print(bard_response)
```

`

Ive tried just copy and pasting the key in the program, creating a enviroment varible and giving the json file path but nothing has worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73451173/google-auth-exceptions-defaultcredentialserror-could-not-automatically-determin)

Comment: Are you sure GOOGLE_API_KEY is properly set in the environment?  Have you tried `print(os.environ.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY'))`?

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct.